# Why is findHomography returning bad result?

Tags: c++, opencv, perspectivecamera

I let the user pick 5 points on two images, which are not the same size (maybe that's the problem).
As the user picks a point on whichever image, I'm pushing that `Point2f` a vector dedicated to that particular image.

So in one instance I have the following data:

```
1. Image 2 at x: 607, and y: 286
2. Image 2 at x: 750, and y: 367
3. Image 2 at x: 527, and y: 353
4. Image 2 at x: 752, and y: 469
5. Image 2 at x: 584, and y: 482
```

--

```
1. Image 1 at x: 301, and y: 343
2. Image 1 at x: 440, and y: 328
3. Image 1 at x: 275, and y: 472
4. Image 1 at x: 478, and y: 457
5. Image 1 at x: 389, and y: 597
```

However `findHomohraphy` returns

```
[0, 0, 0;

 0, 0, 0;

 0, 0, 0]
```

This is what my function does once it gets a hold of 2 vectors with 4 points.

```
Mat tranform( std::vector<cv::Point2f> src, std::vector<cv::Point2f> dst) {
     transMatrix = findHomography(src, dst, CV_RANSAC);
     std::cout << transMatrix << std::endl;
     return transMatrix;
}
```

I also tried changing the method argument of findHomohraphy from `0` to `CV_RANSAC`.

I'm debugging a bit further, and I'm having trouble printing the `Point2f` vector. Maybe I'm not assigning it correctly

This is what I'm currently doing in an image window callback function.

```
imgOnePoints.assign(imgOneIndex, Point2f(x,y));
```

Comment: I think it can't find any similarities.

Comment: I might not be assigning the vector correctly

Comment: A general piece of advice with finding homography; More points = better. Especially with Ransac, as this allows for outliers to be ignored. A zero matrix result means that it was unable to find the homography (doesn't always mean there isn't one ofcource)

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I tried 6-7 points before but it was still being unfriendly when it came to transforming it. I had somewhat odd points picked on the desired orientation picture. If you're interested to know what I mean i'll email it to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i really wasn't assigning the vector correctly

I fixed it by implemented assignment using `push_back`

```
imgOnePoints.push_back(Point2f(x,y));
```

Now I'm getting the following result

```
[9.160730442076495, -1.849442562331516, -180.7111392985398;
  4.977742556341154, 2.013216209765684, -1267.475935610038;
  0.007750660030394876, -0.0003148605099947704, 0.9999999999999999]
```